# Node.JS + Socket.io + MySql: Query callback called only 1 out of 2 times

Tags: mysql, node.js, callback, socket.io

I am implementing a chat system on node.js with the socket.io mysql module:

```
client.on('message', function (data) {
    if (!channel) {
        console.error('Cannot send message: no channel created');
        return;
    }

    console.log('message received');
    channel.addMessage(data.conversationID, data.text);
});
```

Channel is the object which implement messaging logic. addMessage is as follows:

```
addMessage: function (conversationID, text) {
    var that = this;

    // Inner function that inserts a message record in the database and optionally notifies
    // the other connected client
    var insertMessageIn = function(conversation) { ... };

    // If a conversation is already open, uses its reference directly. Otherwise, performs a select query and adds the
    // result to the set of open conversations
    this.open(conversationID, function (conversation) {
        if (that.senderUserID != conversation.StarterUserID || conversation.TotalMessages > 2 * that.MAX_UNANSWERED_MESSAGES) {
            insertMessageIn(conversation);
            return;
        }

        console.log('counting total messages');
        // Prevents an user to importunate another one by continuously sending messages. At most 5 messages can
        // be sent without a reply
        that.lockAndQuery('messages', 'SELECT TotalMessages FROM conversations WHERE ID = ?', [conversation.ID], function (error, rows) {
            if (error) {
                console.error('Cannot read total messages ' + error.stack);
                return;
            }

            var totalMessages = rows[0].TotalMessages;
            conversation.TotalMessages = totalMessages;
            console.log('total messages ' + totalMessages);

            if (that.senderUserID == conversation.StarterUserID && 
                    totalMessages >= that.MAX_UNANSWERED_MESSAGES && 
                    totalMessages < 2 * that.MAX_UNANSWERED_MESSAGES) {
                var rawQuery = 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS ReplyMessageCount FROM messages WHERE ConversationID = ? AND SenderUserID = ?';
                var params = [conversation.ID, conversation.TargetUserID];

                that.chatHandler.dbConnection.query(rawQuery, params, function (error, rows) {
                    if (error) {
                        console.error('Cannot count messages ' + error.stack);
                        return;
                    }

                    var count = rows[0].ReplyMessageCount;

                    // If count is gt 0, the receiver has replied at least one: you can keep messaging normally
                    if (count > 0)
                        insertMessageIn(conversation);
                    else
                        that.clientSocket.emit('too many messages without answer', null);
                });
            } else {
                insertMessageIn(conversation);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

This prevents users starting a conversation to flood the other user with messages. The lockAndQuery method is to prevent deadlocks and is implemented as follows:

```
lockAndQuery: function (tableName, query, params, callback) {
    var that = this;

    this.chatHandler.dbConnection.query('LOCK TABLES ' + tableName + ' WRITE', function (error, result) {
        if (error) {
            console.error('Cannot acquire lock ' + error.stack);
            return;
        }

        that.chatHandler.dbConnection.query(query, params, function (e, r) {
            callback(e, r);
            that.chatHandler.dbConnection.query('UNLOCK TABLES');
        });
    });
}
```

You may notice that altough the select is on table conversation, the lock is on table messages. This is wanted because there is a trigger on messages that updates a field on conversation.

The problem is the following. In my test page, I have a cycle that sends 6 messages to the server. Since a conversation with the used ID is already open and with some messages, all of those should be rejected by the server.
In particular, the sequence of log information I would expect to see on the server is:

```
message received
counting total messages
total messages 5
```

repeated 6 times. But this is not what I get. The actual output is:

```
message received
counting total messages
total messages 5

message received
counting total messages

message received
counting total messages
total messages 5

message received
counting total messages

message received
counting total messages
total messages 5

message received
counting total messages
```

As you can see, the code reachs the query callback only half of the times, without launching any errors. Why?